# compute percentage of total area covered by each category of raster

Tags: qgis

I have a raster Land use classification file. It has 7 categories: `forest, shrubs, snow/glaciers, grassland, water body, barren land, agriculture land`. All of them are represented by a number each. So 1 would be forest, 2 would be shurb land and so on.

I need to get the area covered by all of them separately.

> for eg. forest = 40%, shrubs = 10%, agriculture  = 15% and so on or something similar results, in terms of percent of gross value would also work.

I looked into 1 or 2 other questions which recommended to re classify first by assigning 1 for forest and 0 for all others, use zonal stats to find number of cell, then multiply by the cell area. It works but its too lengthy process and besides I have to do this for other rasters as well, not only for this land use file.

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: `GRASS r.report` can be accessed through Processing Toolbox (-p option). It can be run as batch process, too.

Comment: Glad it worked, thanks. Care to post as answer? (sorry, as I do not have appropriate dataset.)